# checking the value of the dropdownlist datatextfield

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am binding my dropdownlist from the cs file.The value contained in the struser_type can be C,E or S. If it is C I want to display it as customer, E then employee and S then supplier. How to check it and display the corresponding value in the dropdown textfield.

```
            ddl_user_type.DataSource = OBJLIST;
            ddl_user_type.DataTextField = "struser_type";
            ddl_user_type.DataValueField = "iuser_id";
            ddl_user_type.DataBind();
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to make change in the data source OBJLIST before you bind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following way to accomplish this:

First Collect all data from DB and iterate trough it using normal for loop:

Asssuming `OBJLIST` is as `Dataset`:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < OBJLIST.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
ListItem  item = new ListItem();
if(OBJLIST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["struser_type"].toString() == "C")
   item.Text="Customer";

else if......

item.Value = OBJLIST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["iuser_id"].toString();

ddl_user_type.Items.Add(item);
}
```

This Should work for you....